# Good references to replace AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am quite new to Spring Security and have a question regarding migrating OAuth2 to Spring Security 5.2+.

Our team is clearing our tech debt in Spring Security and realized that Spring Security OAuth2 component is being deprecated and replaced as a part of Spring Security 5.2 or higher.

I am currently working on replacing the deprecated APIs with the newly introduced ones in Spring Security 5.3.3 and am stuck on replacing **AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter**. Tried finding a good example or the equivalent behaviors in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter but couldn't quite get a good luck.

I was wondering if there is any good references to replace the deprecated APIs with the new ones or not. What I am interested in are the following interfaces:

TokenStore
TokenEnhancer
TokenConverter

To talk about the behavior, I'd like to create the OAuth token with JWT format with Basic Authentication through /oauth/token.

I would be grateful if anyone could give me good advices or directions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Actually I myself will answer my question.

What I did for replacing AuthorizationServer was utilizing a Filter.

I added my own Filter named something like OauthAuthenticationFilter which extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter, overrided the endpoint to "oauth/token" added it to the httpSecurity in WebSecurityConfig. So in detail steps,

1. Create a class OauthAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
2. Override attemptAuthentication in OauthAuthenticationFilter, create the authentication and pass it to authenticationManager.authenticate()
3. Override successfulAuthentication in OauthAuthenticationFilter, create the bearer token, add it to the response header "Authorization", and write it to the HTTP response
4. Configure authorizeRequests in WebSecurityConfig. Configure oauth2ResourceServer, jwtAuthenticationConverter and jwtDecoder.
5. Create an instance of OauthAuthenticationFilter in WebSecurityConfig, override the endpoint to "/oauth/token" in setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher, and add the filter to the httpSecurity

By doing that we can safely remove the old AuthorizationServer, uplift the spring security to 5.3+ and wait until a new AuthorizationServer package is released:
https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server